# Highlight series of cells every time word occurs

Tags: excel

If I have the status of a task in cell C12 and the task title and description in cells C10 & C11, is there a way to highlight all three cells based on the status cell?

E.g. If C12="Completed" then fill C10:C12 with colour

I'm fine with that part but I have the sheet set up in a grid e.g. week 1 has 6 tasks, all with status cells, and there are several weeks.

**I want a formula to use in conditional formatting which will highlight all occurances where the specific text occurs (Completed) and ALSO the two cells above it**

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Slai That works for those three cells but no other occurrences. The status of "Completed" can occur anywhere in the range B10:F36 so I'm not too sure how to do it

Comment: on what rows or ranges are the status cells? `B12:F12,B36:F36`? You can do it with 3 conditional format formulas - one for all task titles, one for all  task descriptions, and one for all  status cells

Comment: @Slai The Status cells are in all of the following cells: B12:F12;B15:F15;B19:F19;B22:F22;B26:F26;B29:F29;B33:F33;B36:F36

The areas I want to fill are two above each status cell (so B10:B12 will be affected by cell B12 ETC)

Answer (score 0):

Using one formula for the whole range `B10:F36` seems a bit complicated because the status cells are not on rows that are multiple of any number. You can try the formula below after selecting the range `B10:F15;B17:F22;B24:F29;B31:F36` (don't select rows 16,23, and 30):

```
= OffSet($A$1, LookUp( Row()+2, {12;15;19;22;26;29;33;36} ) - 1, Column() - 1) = "Completed"
```

Comment: was great and found that = COUNTIF( B12:B14, "Completed" ) works when applied to the range $B$12:$F$38, works like a charm :D